# how can I call a class to run from program.cs in my form.cs

Tags: c#, forms, class

I am having trouble getting my class to from program.cs to run in form.cs when I request it to. I have tried numbers methods but they don't seem to work, I have used the method that I have used to send variable across between the two files and that didn't work and I have searched but don't understand what the code is doing or where to put it. What I want it to do is run that class in the backgroundworker but the variable method I was shown before doesn't work for the class.

here is the class I want to run

```
public static class DirectoryInfoExtensions
{

     //Copies all files from one directory to another.
    public static void CopyTo(this DirectoryInfo source, string destDirectory, bool recursive)
    {
        if (source == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (destDirectory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destDirectory");

        // If the source doesn't exist, we have to throw an exception.
        if (!source.Exists)
           throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory not found: " + source.FullName);
       //  Compile the target.
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(destDirectory);
         //If the target doesn't exist, we create it.
        if (!target.Exists)
            target.Create();

        // Get all files and copy them over.
       foreach (FileInfo file in source.GetFiles())
        {
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name), true);
        }

        // Return if no recursive call is required.
        if (!recursive)
            return;

        // Do the same for all sub directories.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in source.GetDirectories())
       {
          CopyTo(directory, Path.Combine(target.FullName, directory.Name), recursive);
      }
   }
}
```

here is where I want to run it in form.cs

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Some punctuation would do wonders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to i call a variable from the form.cs file to the program.cs file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908073/how-to-i-call-a-variable-from-the-form-cs-file-to-the-program-cs-file)

Comment: i have tried that code but it didn't work for a class

Comment: Bobthe, all in all this is the 5th question about the same problem. We would appreciate if you put some effort in phrasing and formatting a question, and follow up on comments and requests for clarification.

Comment: different questions ie problems about the same piece of code

Comment: @bobthe: Do you see the `Edit` link under your question? And do you see Martinho's comment? ...

Comment: The archives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908073/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900756/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899740/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899281

Comment: these are all different question to do diffident tasks but i can see when i am not wanted so i am not going to post any more.

Comment: @bobthemac: Don't take offense where none is intended. We're trying to help you in the most efficient way possible. Stack Overflow has created some pretty good systems to help people get their questions answered, but people who are new here often don't understand the systems. These comments are a way for people to help you understand what you need to do and pay attention to. Deciding never to use StackOverflow, instead of listening to the advice of Henk, et al, will be shooting yourself in the foot (and won't hurt us in the least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to run the CopyTo method? That should be easy enough. You can either invoke it explicitly:

```
DirectoryInfoExtensions.CopyTo(source, "C:\DestinationDirectory", true);
```

... or as an extension method:

```
source.CopyTo("C:\DestinationDirectory", true);
```

Of course, if your extensions are not in the same namespace as your form class, you'll need to make sure that you are using the namespace that DirectoryInfoExtensions is in, by placing something like this at the top of your file:

```
using Utilities; // replace Utilities with whatever namespace DirectoryInfoExtensions is in
```

And you'll need to have a `source` variable of type DirectoryInfo.

```
var source = new DirectoryInfo("C:\SourceDirectory");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DirectoryInfo.CopyTo("<source folder>, "<target folder>", true)
```

Does it not work this way? What error are you seeing?

Comment: You need to substitute real folder names for my placeholders